# Does Azure have any REST API service/wrapper for Ms SQL DB?

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

Does Azure have any REST API service/wrapper for Ms SQL DB? - Something similar like Dreamfactory?

Comment: You mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ?

Comment: @RachelAmbler No, this is for management. I need REST API wrapper for data access. I need a REST API service for data access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected as per David's comment. You can no longer configure ODATA access to your database in Azure :(. Instead you have to write some code. It is quite easy to wrap your DB up in an ODATA web service using ASP.NET and Entity Framework.

[More info on ODATA and ASP.NET  here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

Alternatively, you can use something like [Restier](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/)

or, you can pay for Dreamfactory...

Comment: That service never went GA, and has been discontinued.

Comment: Would love to know the reason this service never went GA. Seems like it would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create an OData endpoint for a SQL Database is to use [ODATA in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) or the simpler [RESTier](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/), hosted in IIS or an [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/).

Comment: Ty David. Unfortunately, I wanted ready solution without any development. And this is why I surprised that Azure/Ms SQL still dosn't have such feature from the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be consuming the data in SharePoint, BCS may be a code-free option.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-an-external-list-from-a-sql-azure-table-with-business-connectivity-services-and-secure-store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95